# Winning strategy for a player in a game with Alice and Bob

Tags: game-theory

I was solving this problem :https://codeforces.com/contest/1841/problem/A ,I know it is a programmingm problem but inherently it does involves principles of game theory. What I don't understand is that if suppose Alice is starting in the question , then won't he always win if he selects the (n-1) cards , replaces the sum (n-1) back , now if n>2 then he should always win.
Also, can anyone give me on what metric is the optimal decision for a player is decided?

Thanks

Comment: The game as presented is a bit unusual in that the player who cannot make a legal move **wins**. The strategy you outlined means Bob see the numbers $\{n-1,1\}$, can not make a legal move, so wins. So this is  a bad strategy for Alice.

Comment: Right, I thought to be opposite @Ingix

Comment: For $n>3$ couldn't Alice select $n-2$ $1$s, leaving $(1,1,n-2)$, then Bob is forced to select the two $1$s to leave $(2,n-2)$ and so Alice always wins in these cases?

Comment: For n =4, they might be equal so Alice might not win @DavidChew but yes.. it should be true for n>4

Comment: This is almost misère Nim ("misère" meaning winner & loser of the normal game are swapped). The collections of repeated integer values become the heaps, with one fewer stones than there are repetitions of the integers. The difference is that on occasions a new stone is added to the board, either in an existing heap or in a new heap. However, that difference does break the normal misère Nim strategy.

Comment: @PaulSinclair why is that you can only select two entries?

Comment: I never said that. However, looking back at the problem statement, I see that it does state the game starts out with all $1$s. I had missed that, and thought it could start with an arbitrary list of starting integers. My apologies. Your strategy does work for the non-misère game with this fixed starting position for $n > 2$. For the actual misère game, David Chew's strategy works for $n > 4$.